# iptables: How to allow SSH through debian router?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, iptables

This is the network map:

```
  [External computer]---[Router]---[SSH server]

            EXTERNAL NET <=|=> INTERNAL NET
```

Router is doing SNAT and port translation:

```
#~ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth-external -j SNAT --to-source $EXT_ROUTER_IP
#~ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth-external -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination $SSH_SERVER:22
```

This works well, i can do ssh to the SSH server from outside of my network doing ssh -p 2222 $ROUTER_IP.

The problem comes when I set the default policy for FORWARD to DROP.

```
#~ iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Logically now the packets to internal SSH server are been dropped.

I'm trying with

```
#~ iptables -A FORWARD -i eth-external -o eth-internal -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#~ iptables -A FORWARD -o sth-external -i eth-internal -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

No work.

```
#~ iptables -A FORWARD -i eth-external -o eth-internal -j ACCEPT
#~ iptables -A FORWARD -o sth-external -i eth-internal -j ACCEPT
```

Works.

But I don't want to allow all traffic between this two interfaces, only SSH packets.

Any one can help me?

Thanks!

## EDIT:

Finally i got this working...

```
#~ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth-external -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination $SSH_SERVER:22
#~ iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

thanks @davidgo

Comment: As you are port forwarding from port 2222, shouldn't it be set in your forward rule instead of 22?

Comment: @Zina i think no, because PREROUTING rule do the port translation.
See this http://jensd.be/wp-content/uploads/iptables_chains.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accepting traffic from port 2222 back to port 22.  You need the lines

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth-external -o eth-internal -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o sth-external -i eth-internal -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

or, possibly better

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth-external -o eth-internal -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Which which will match outbound packets in response to an inbound request.

Comment: Finally works, thanks!
I like your approach "iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" It's save me a lot of rules.